# prepositions in or on

Tags: prepositions

I am confused with preposition.
I have experiences in the field of children and young people or
I have experiences on the field of children and young people?
which is correct?

Comment: Children and young people are not a _field_ as such.  _I have experience in the field of paediatrics._ is more likely.

Comment: Isn't it better to say: `I have experiences with children and young people`

Comment: @Ormoz, actually it would be experience, singular, not plural.

Answer (score -2):

Say "In the field of", like "you are expert in ..." and "writing on .."

When to use “on” and when to use “in”:

### In

In denotes “rest at”:

> PLACE: He lives in the country. He lives in America.
>
> TIME: I’ll be there in an hour.
>
> MANNER: The child ran down the steps in tears.
>
> REFERENCE: In my opinion we need a referendum. They are happy in their marriage.

I've got expertise *in* something.

### On

*On* indicates proximity and position above or outside:

> PLACE: He sat on the fence.
>
> TIME: He was not thinking well on that occasion.
>
> REFERENCE: He asked my opinion on the matter.
>
> CONDITION: We’ll hire him on your recommendation.

He was writing *on* this topic.